# How to do this XQuery with order by?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following example html:

```xml
<birdbook>
    <family page="200">
        <family_name>owls</family_name>
        <latin_name>Strigiformes<latin_name>
    </family>
    <family page="312">
        <family_name>woodpeckers</family_name>
        <latin_name>Picidea<latin_name>
    </family>
</birdbook>
```

I want to do XQuery which returns family names ordered by latin names inside result elements. I tried to do the following:

```
for $x in doc("birdbook.xml")//family_name
   order by $x/latin_name ascending
   return
   <result>{$x}</result>
```

Result would be peckers first and then owls. Now I'm still getting owls first. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Martin has given you a solution, but the answer to your question is: you are using the path expression `$x/latin_name` which selects nothing,  because `$x` is a `family_name` element, and a `family_name` element does not have a `latin_name` child.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   for $x in doc("birdbook.xml")//family
   order by $x/latin_name ascending
   return
   <result>{$x/family_name}</result>
```